# three.jsのShaderMaterialのフラグメントシェーダーの記述で、配列の添字に変数が使えない？

Tags: javascript, three.js, glsl

three.jsのShaderMaterialのフラグメントシェーダーの記述のところで、
配列の添字を変数にすると描画されません。
（ ①だと描画されるが、②だと描画されない ）

配列の添字に変数は使えないのでしょうか？
または使う方法はありますか？
動的に配列の要素を選択したいです。

```
<script id="fragmentShader" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
void main(){
    float ary[1];
    ary[0] = 1.0;

    gl_FragColor = vec4(ary[0], 0.0, 0.0, 1.0); // ① OK

    int r = 0;
    // gl_FragColor = vec4(ary[r], 0.0, 0.0, 1.0); // ② NG
}
</script>
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[WebGL](https://registry.khronos.org/webgl/specs/latest/1.0/)は

- [OpenGL ES Version 2.0.25](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL/specs/es/2.0/es_full_spec_2.0.pdf)
- [OpenGL ES Shading Language Version 1.00](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL/specs/es/2.0/GLSL_ES_Specification_1.00.pdf)

を参照していますが、後者の [Appendix A: Limitations for ES 2.0](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL/specs/es/2.0/GLSL_ES_Specification_1.00.pdf#page=115) に

> ### 5 indexing of Arrays, Vectors and Matrices
>
> Definition:
> `constant-index-expressions` are a superset of `constant-expressions`. Constant-index-expressions can include loop indices as defined in Appendix A section 4.

とか言っていて最終的に

> [image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

となっていて配列の添え字は定数しか認められていません。

---

一応、

```
if (r == 0)
    gl_FragColor = vec4(ary[0], 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
else if (r == 1)
    gl_FragColor = vec4(ary[1], 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
```

みたいな涙ぐましい努力をすることが認められています。

Comment: ありがとうございました！勉強になりました。if文で書いてみます。